# How to convert type in golang?

Tags: go

I need to hid a password.
I get (mismatched types `[]byte` and `int`).
How can i fix it? How can I convert from `int` to `[]byte`?

```
package main

import ("fmt"; "github.com/howeyc/gopass")

func main() {
    var user string
    maping := map[string]int{"dasha": 123, "mike": 777}

    fmt.Println("Enter username: ")
    fmt.Scan(&user)
    fmt.Printf("Enter password: ")
    pass, err := gopass.GetPasswd()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    if pass == maping[user] {
        fmt.Println("bingo")
    }else{
        fmt.Println("the login or password is not correct")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the conversion with `strconv`'s `Atoi()` function:

```
i, err := strconv.Atoi("-42")
```

And you'd convert your `[]byte` to a `string` with

```
s := string(byteArray[:])
```

So the combination is

```
i, err := strconv.Atoi(string(pass[:]))
```

Comment: Note that, Golang allows you to convert []byte to string (or vice versa) simply by doing an explicit typecast, because the underlying type of a string actually *is* a []byte.

But as you would notice, same doesn't hold for string and int types. You need something more than just a typecast (a function) to do this conversion.